# Mvc maproute multiple page levels

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there anyway I can reduce the amount of duplication mapRoute registration in global.ascx file for mulit page levels as below.

```
    routes.MapRoute("Article-level1",
                "{sluglevel1}/article/{id}/{article-title}",
                new { controller = "article", action = "detail", id = UrlParameter.Optional });


routes.MapRoute("Article-level2",
                "{sluglevel1}/{sluglevel2}/article/{id}/{article-title}",
                new { controller = "article", action = "detail", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute("Article-level3",
                "{sluglevel1}/{sluglevel2}/{sluglevel3}/article/{id}/{article-title}",
                new { controller = "article", action = "detail", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

... more levels 4 to 10 ...
```

Please let me know if there is better way to do.

Comment: Hi, If you find an answer useful please mark it as resolved so other users can see how you resolved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore the "Catch-all" route parameters: [Handling a Variable Number of Segments in a URL Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#handling_a_variable_number_of_segments_in_a_url_pattern).

But you will need to change the structure of your routes to something like this:

`"article/{id}/{article-title}/{*sluglevels}"`

Comment: this is not possible. I need to have page levels at front of article url segments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple loop an generate dynamically your routes:

```
int levelCount = 5;

for (int i = 1; i <= levelCount; i++)
{
    string routeName = "Article-level" + i;

    IEnumerable<string> levels = Enumerable.Range(1, i).Select(r => string.Format("{{sluglevel{0}}}", r));
    string url = string.Join("/", levels);
    url += "/article/{id}/{article-title}";

    routes.MapRoute(routeName, url,
        new { controller = "article", action = "detail", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

You will need to import `System.Linq` and `System.Collections.Generic`

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```